# Is SVG is the correct technology for future project

Tags: canvas, svg, web, fabricjs, snap.svg

I'm not 100% sure stackoverflow is the correct place for the question so forgive me if I cause annoyance! I also appreciate this is quite a commercial question!

I am finding it very hard to find any information around the activeness of SVG as a standard and what the future of SVG might be. I'm basically trying to avoid backing a technology that major browsers will be dumping in a few years (but who can predict the future?!?!)

My plan is to export SVGs from something like Adobe Illustrator..then allow customers to edit them with web tech such as snapsvg. This would let people edit the svg's and then we can do stuff for them in terms of rendering and printing (as PDF).

The alternative to SVG would be something like canvas using fabric js to enable the same thing over the top of a custom data model (json/xml).

If anyone has any advice or information that might help me make a decision I would really appreciate it. If this isn't the right place for this question any advice where to look would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think SVG is going away? SVG and Canvas are not completely interchangeable technologies

Comment: If your destination is.print, SVG should be your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG isn't going away soon (SMIL svg markup may be though, so I wouldn't animate via that). SVG in some ways has come into it's own with things like mobile, where low size images are wanted, especially for things like logos.

Personally, if you want to use something like Illustrator and be able to manipulate images, especially if you may at some point want to animate parts of the image, I would go with SVG. There's various libraries for it, and Snap.svg and svg.js are 2 of the main ones (with d3.js being the one if wanting to do graphs and charts).

If you are passing around images for development to other graphic designers etc, I would stick with SVG at the source. You can always use fabric.js with exported SVG later if there is some specific reason for it.

Comment: Note, if you are unsure which library/tech to use, it may be useful to try and write your code slightly abstracted from the library. Eg write your own func which will draw a shape (which calls Snap or whatever). Then later if you want to change libraries, you only then need to change your few functions. Rather than have Snap or SVG.js nested all over the place in your code which you then need to swap out.

Answer (score 1):

Fabricjs developer here.

If you are handling vector data, SVG is a good choice.
If your application and customers wants to create simple graphic SVG is good enough.

When it comes to pictures, filtering, pixel editing, and manipulation like blurring or smudging, SVG starts to not be the best choice anymore.

Also Text editing has some limits in SVG, since there is not concept of line breaks and this can be annoying for users or developer that have to build this concept on top of TSPANS.

Filtering is slow compared to webgl and is harder to obtain the exact same rendering across different browsers and across illustrator and browsers.

When it comes to printing, you often have to change format from SVG, going over PDF, that do not support all the SVG features.

Canvas technology from the other side is harder to use if not helped by a library that will put its own constrain.
Is generally slower modify pixel versus modifying dom elements with svgs.

It offers you a PNG or JPEG export out of the box that of course do not offer any kind of manipulation of the design or product you were creating after the export, while an SVG can benefit from a sort of non destructive editing.

In the specific case of fabricjs ( since you mention it ) the library helps you to create a serializable version of your document that then you can re render at higher resolutions or save, load and modify again (export resolution depends on the browser you use for rendering likely 12.000 x 12.000 on firefox and chrome or a bit higher)

The tool that best fit in my opinion depends on the type of content you want to offer to the user of your application. If pictures are involved, i would go with canvas and some kind of library to help you save/restore the design and abstract the code. (Fabricjs is good, there may be other alternatives that are equal or better )